# Is the curve $(\sqrt t \cos(\frac1t),\sqrt t \sin(\frac1t))$ rectifiable and continuously differenciable?

Tags: real-analysis, vector-analysis

I have a curve $C$ given by $\gamma:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb R^2$

$$\gamma(t) =  \begin{cases} 
      (0,0) & t=0 \\
    (\sqrt t \cos(\frac1t),\sqrt t \sin(\frac1t)) & t>      0
   \end{cases}$$

I would like to find out whether this curve is rectifiable and continuously differentiable. I already figured, that this function must be continuous, since sine and cosine are limited. 
However, when it comes down to finding out whether $C$ is rectifiable, i.e :

$$\sup \Big \{ \sum_{i=1}^m \|\gamma(t_i)-\gamma(t_{i-1}) \|: m\in\mathbb N \Big \} < \infty$$

with $\{t_0,....,t_m\}$ denoting a partition of $[0,1]$ seems a bit harder. Intuitively after looking at a plot, it seems that this curve is not rectifiable, but I do not know how to proof it. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The derivative is unbounded as $t \downarrow 0$, that tells you something about whether or not it is $C^1$. A little work shows that $\|\gamma'(t)\|^2 = {1 \over 4t} + { 1\over t^3}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $\tau_i=\frac1{i\pi}$, we have $\gamma(\tau_i)=\bigl((-1)^i\sqrt{1/ i},0\bigr)$ and hence with the partition $\{t_0,t_1,t_2,\ldots,t_{m-1},t_m\}=\{0,\tau_{m-1},\tau_{m-2},\ldots,\tau_1,1\}$ 
$$\begin{align}\sum_{i=1}^m\|\gamma(t_i)-\gamma(t_{i-1})\|&=\frac1{\sqrt{m-1}}+\sum_{i=1}^{m-1}\left(\frac1{\sqrt {m-i}}+\frac1{\sqrt{m-i+1}}\right) +\|\gamma(\tau_1-\gamma(1)\|\\
&>\sum_{i=1}^{m-1}\frac1{\sqrt i} \end{align}$$
and as $\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac1{\sqrt i}$ diverges, the supremum we look for cannot be finite.

Comment: Opps, I forgot to sprinkle in some factors $\frac1{\sqrt \pi}$, but that doesn't reall ymatter ...